# subViews frame when oreiantion changes

Tags: iphone

in my app i am having many ViewControllers.Most of them have tableViews as subView.Many cells of the tableView have label and textField as subView.When from potrait mode to landscape mode i change,tableView gets resized (i.e width and height of tableView gets adjusted to that of screen).But my labels and textField width wont get changed.Also actionsheets.If i print width and height in landscape it is(320.0,460.0).so how to adjust the size of my subViews when there is change in orientation

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the subviews automatically resize when the available space changes by calling something like

```
someSubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

when creating them.

In Interface Builder, in the Size Inspector for you views (Command-3), you just click on the two arrows within the square under "Autosizing" in the Size Inspector to make them both bright red, which is the equivalent of the above code.